# How to extract the SVN Commit logs to a notepad from MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

Can anybody help me to extract/export the comments(Comments which we include while committing the changes to SVN) from SVN to a notepad using MSBuild.

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
<Exec Command="svn log ..\properties\assemblyinfo.cs --xml > ..\releasenotes.xml"/>
```

to my msbuild file.  I'm updating assemblyinfo automatically with the SVN version number else where in the msbuild file.

This is xml format but if you remove the --xml it will be plain text.